# How can I make a cherry-pick with PyGithub?

Tags: python, github, pygithub

I am using PyGithub in a personal project.
I have two repositories: upstream and fork.
I want to backport a commit from my fork's master branch into an older version branch. And then submit a pull request to the upstream's older version branch with that commit.
PyGithub seems intuitive, but I can't understand if it's possible to perform a cherry-pick with that library... Can anyone help?